# How to initialize a pointer to a specific memory address in C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, casting

An interesting discussion about this started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933263/questions-every-good-c-c-developer-should-be-able-to-answer/3933402#3933402) but no one have been able to provide the C++ way of doing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int* address = (int *)0x604769; 
  printf("Memory address is: 0x%p\n", address);

  *address = 0xdead; 
  printf("Content of the address is: 0x%p\n", *address);

  return 0;
}
```

What is the most appropriate way of doing such a thing in C++?

Comment: Apart from changing to C++ constructs, there is no real difference to the way you would do it in C++.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In C++, always prefer `reinterpret_cast` over a C-cast. It's so butt ugly that someone will immediately spot the danger.

Example:

```
int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x12345678);
```

That thing hurts my eyes, and I like it.

Comment: The sample code is in C and the OP knows it is. He is asking if there is a better way to do the same in C++. In a device driver you may well know the absolute address you wish to write to. I remember doing this kind of thing in my early days with MS-DOS to write directly to the memory screen. With macros - of course.

Comment: Accessing hardware registers via addresses is common practice in embedded systems.  They are either defined as constant pointers or declared using `#define`.

Comment: Why did you go to `void*`?  OP's code want a pointer to an `int`

Comment: @John: Good point. Changed it. Thanks.

Comment: @CashCow:  Sure - but you're doing implementation-specific casting no matter what, and `reinterpret_cast` is the C++ way of doing it.  It's better because it's easier to find, and flags this as a potentially unsafe operation should anybody try porting this.

Comment: @Coincoin what if the address is already occupied?

Comment: Is there a need, since C++17, to use `std::launder`? like that: `int* ptr = std:: launder(reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x12345678));` This relates to @Lokanath comment above: "_what if the address is already occupied?_", or taken a bit differently: _what if another live pointer already points there?_ Then `std::launder` becomes important I believe.

Answer (score 2):

There is NO standard and portable way to do so. Non-portable ways may include reinterpret_cast(someIntRepresentingTheAddress).

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
void *address=(void *) 0xdead; // But as mentioned, it's non-standard

address=(void *) 0xdeadbeef; // Some other address
```

Comment: If the question is "what is the C++ way" then you took a bad situation and made it worse by going with `void*`

Comment: don't even listen to them, void* are underappreciated due to fear lol. this is a purist answer in a way

Answer (score 1):

In C++, I prefer to declare the pointers as constant pointers in a header file:

```
volatile uint8_t * const UART_STATUS_REGISTER = (uint8_t *) 0xFFFF4000;
```

In the C language, this is usually implemented using a macro:

```
#define UART_STATUS_REGISTER ((volatile uint8_t * const) 0xFFFF4000)
```

In the rest of the source code, the memory address is referenced via the symbolic name.

Answer (score 1):

I would add that you can call the placement operator for new if you want an objects constructor called when assigning it at the specified address:

```
int *pLoc = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x604769);
int *address = new (pLoc) int (1234); // init to a value
```

This is also used for memory caching objects.  Create a buffer and then assign an object to it.

```
unsigned char *pBuf = new unsigned char[sizeof(CMyObject) + alignment_size];
allign_buf(pBuf);
CMyObject *pMyObj = new (pBuf) CMyObject;
```