# Does my code for writing into a register need any corrections?

Tags: c, embedded

My question is generic and not related to any specific microcontroller.
Below is code for writing to a hardware register address. In this code, I'm trying to write several values, one after the other.

```
unsigned int *p;  //declare a pointer

p = (int *) 0x200;  //point to hardware register address

*p = 0x12;  // write to hardware register address

*p = 0xA5;  // write to hardware register address

*p = 0xff;  // write to hardware register address
```

Does the above need any correction?

Comment: What do you mean by correction?  This post might be some help: [How to initialize a pointer to a specific memory address in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934775/how-to-initialize-a-pointer-to-a-specific-memory-address-in-c)

Comment: In your architecture, would you need to insert memory barriers between the three assignments to `*p`?

Answer (score 9):

If you're writing to a hardware register, you'll typically want to use the `volatile` keyword:

```
volatile unsigned int *p;
```

Without the `volatile`, an optimizing compiler might conclude that the first two writes are unnecessary (because the value is immediately overwritten) and optimize them away.

This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_C_and_C.2B.2B) has more information on `volatile`.

Comment: Also [this](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4023801/Introduction-to-the-Volatile-Keyword) on Embedded.com.

Comment: An alternative is to use [Memory barriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier).  We don't have the semantics of the register (write only, etc).  It is possible if this is an interrupt mask register that **memory barriers** would be better.  If the register is updated asynchronously by *non-CPU* hardware or if the writes are stateful, `volatile` is the best.  Maybe *stateful* is the wrong terminology, *write 1 to clear* is an example of what I am thinking of.